# Why does Has.All.Property(nameof(Type.Namespace)) fail when attempting to assert on a collection of Types using NUnit?

Tags: c#, nunit

I want to assert that all the types I am interested in are in the expected namespace using NUnit.

```cs
IReadOnlyCollection<Type> types = GetInterestingTypes(); // Method defined elsewhere.
Assert.That(types, Has.All.Property(nameof(Type.Namespace)).StartsWith("MyNamespace"));
```

This fails with ArgumentException `Property Namespace not found on ...`.

However, the equivalent non-collection assert `Has.Property(nameof(Type.Namespace)).StartsWith("MyNamespace")` succeeds.

Minimal reproducible example:

```cs
using System;
using System.Linq;
using System.Reflection;
using System.Runtime.CompilerServices;

using NUnit.Framework;

namespace MyNamespace
{
    internal class MyTests
    {
        [Test]
        public void TestsWithinNamespace()
        {
            var types = new[] {typeof(Foo), typeof(NestedNamespace.Bar)};

            foreach (var type in types)
            {
                // Passes
                Assert.That(type, Has.Property(nameof(Type.Namespace)).StartsWith("MyNamespace"));
            }

            // Fails
            Assert.That(types, Has.All.Property(nameof(Type.Namespace)).StartsWith("MyNamespace"));
        }
    }

    public class Foo { }

    namespace NestedNamespace
    {
        public class Bar { }
    }
}
```

When running this test, we get

```
System.ArgumentException : Property Namespace was not found on MyNamespace.Foo.
Parameter name: name
   at NUnit.Framework.Constraints.PropertyConstraint.ApplyTo[TActual](TActual actual)
   at NUnit.Framework.Constraints.AllItemsConstraint.ApplyTo[TActual](TActual actual)
   at NUnit.Framework.Assert.That[TActual](TActual actual, IResolveConstraint expression, String message, Object[] args)
   at MyNamespace.MyTests.TestsWithinNamespace()
```

Comment: You asking for properties of classes and the namespace is no property of a class its part of the name of the class.

Comment: @Ralf please see https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.type.namespace.  Yes, the namespace is part of the full name of the class as well.

Comment: Yeep got it wrong. Didn't see that he was looking at a type object and not at the actual class. Even if the word "Type" is mentioned multiple times :(

Comment: Debugging through NUnit i would assume a bug here. When using Property on the AllItemConstraint there is an extra handling when the thing in there is already a type. It does not create a type on the type that you would need for your code to work. Now it searches "Namespace" on Foo and not on the type object of Foo. You should presumably open an issue on the NUnit github. The maintainer should know and at best has a workaround.

Comment: @Ralf That makes a lot of sense, if you want to create an answer I will accept it.

Comment: Not hunting for reputation. The problem seems to be more widespread when using All on Type(s). Even `Has.All.TypeOf<Type>()` fails.  I fear the NUnit guys will tell you you shouldn't do that and use a loop like you already do.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This bug in NUnit has been fixed, however a new release of NUnit containing the fix has not yet been released.
Issue: https://github.com/nunit/nunit/issues/4259
Pull request fixing issue: https://github.com/nunit/nunit/pull/4285